# Eclipse Mars crashing when using Windowbuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

After quite some time I have started working on an project from earlier this year again. This application was build around a GUI that was build with the Eclipse ADT Windowbuilder. Now when I want to view my GUI class with the window builder again Eclipse starts parsing and simply crashes on "refreshing". Here is the crash message I get in the terminal:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-16" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.isVisible(Control.java:3620)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar.timerProc(ProgressBar.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowTimerProc(Display.java:4587)
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
java: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Zusicherung »!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost« nicht erfüllt.
```

So far I have no idea how to fix this. The Windowbuilder has been working a few moths ago with this application.

EDIT:

Here is the Class for the GUI.

```
public class DBDatabaseSystem implements Serializable {

    public static JFrame mainGui;
    public static Config config;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5614180535012598751L;
    private static final String programVersion = "20.07.2015-001";
    private static JTable table;
    private static JSplitPane splitPane;
    private static DefaultTableModel model;
    private static SequentialNumber sequentialNumber = new SequentialNumber();
    private static boolean unsavedChanges = false;
    private static boolean filechooserOpen = false;
    private static JList<String> infoList = new JList<String>();
    private static DefaultListModel<String> infoListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    private static JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    private static String adminEmailLink = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        config = new Config();
        config.loadConfig();

        mainGui = new JFrame();
        mainGui.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getImage("1426088835_Database-Cloud-512.png"));
        mainGui.setTitle("DB Baumaßnahmen Datenbank " + programVersion);
        mainGui.setResizable(false);
        mainGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainGui.setSize(1360, 645);
        mainGui.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center window

        mainGui.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { // event listener for
            // window close action
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                if (config.getDatabaseFile().contains(".dbd")) {
                    if (unsavedChanges == true) {
                        int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainGui,
                                "Es sind noch ungesicherte Änderungen in der Datenbank vorhanden. Möchten sie diese vor dem Beenden speichern?",
                                "Nicht gespiecherte Änderungen an der Datenbank", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if (selection == 0) {
                            saveModel(new File(config.getDatabaseFile()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                config.saveConfig();
            }
        });

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        mainGui.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu menuDatabase = new JMenu("Datenbank");
        menuBar.add(menuDatabase);

        JMenu mnEe = new JMenu("Exportieren");
        menuBar.add(mnEe);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Speicherpfad für Aufträge auswählen...");
        mnEe.add(mntmNewMenuItem);
        mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

                if (fc.showOpenDialog(mainGui) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
                        && fc.getSelectedFile().toString() != "") {
                    // add trailing / to pdf files
                    config.setPdfExportPath(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/");

                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuButtonExportTasks = new JMenuItem("Gewählte Aufträge exportieren");
        mnEe.add(menuButtonExportTasks);
        menuButtonExportTasks.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                    ExportTaskToPDF.exportTaskToPdf("Durchzuführende Baumaßnahmen", getSelectedTasksAsList());
                    ExportTaskToPDF.openExportPath();
                } else {
                    addWarning("Es muss mindestens ein Auftrag zum Export ausgewählt sein.");
                }

            }

        });

        JMenu menuView = new JMenu("Ansicht");
        menuBar.add(menuView);

        JMenu menuHelp = new JMenu("Hilfe");
        menuBar.add(menuHelp);

        JMenuItem menuItemNewDatabase = new JMenuItem("Neue Datenbank anlegen...");
        menuDatabase.add(menuItemNewDatabase);
        menuItemNewDatabase.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setDatabasePath();
                createEmptyModel();
                table.setModel(model);
                initColumModel();
            }
        });

        JSeparator seperatorMenuDatabase = new JSeparator();
        menuDatabase.add(seperatorMenuDatabase);

        JMenuItem MenuItemLoadDatabase = new JMenuItem("Datenbank öffnen...");
        menuDatabase.add(MenuItemLoadDatabase);
        MenuItemLoadDatabase.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                filechooserOpen = true;
                setDatabasePath();
                if (config.getDatabaseFile().contains(".dbd")) {
                    loadModel(new File(config.getDatabaseFile()));
                }
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuItemSaveDatabase = new JMenuItem("Datenbank speichern");
        menuDatabase.add(menuItemSaveDatabase);
        menuItemSaveDatabase.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                saveModel(new File(config.getDatabaseFile()));
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuItemSaveDatabaseAs = new JMenuItem("Datenbank speichern unter...");
        menuDatabase.add(menuItemSaveDatabaseAs);
        menuItemSaveDatabaseAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setDatabasePath();
                saveModel(new File(config.getDatabaseFile()));
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuItemResetView = new JMenuItem("Ansicht zurücksetzen");
        menuView.add(menuItemResetView);

        final JCheckBoxMenuItem chckbxmntmFrameAlwaysOnTop = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Fenster immer im Vordergrund");
        menuView.add(chckbxmntmFrameAlwaysOnTop);
        chckbxmntmFrameAlwaysOnTop.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (chckbxmntmFrameAlwaysOnTop.isSelected()) {
                    mainGui.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                } else {
                    mainGui.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
                }
            }
        });

        menuItemResetView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                initColumModel();
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("Über...");
        menuHelp.add(menuItemAbout);
        menuItemAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGui,
                        "<html>Programm: DB Baumaßnahmen<br><br>Version: " + programVersion
                                + "<br><br>Entwickler: <br><br>Support: " + adminEmailLink,
                        "Über", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem menuItemCheckUpdates = new JMenuItem("Auf Updates prüfen...");
        menuItemCheckUpdates.setEnabled(false);
        menuHelp.add(menuItemCheckUpdates);
        mainGui.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        mainGui.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setEnabled(false);
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.55);
        splitPane.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        splitPane.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        splitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        panel.add(splitPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                unsavedChanges = true; // catch if there was a change
            }
        });

        if (config.getDatabaseFile().contains(".dbd")) {
            loadModel(new File(config.getDatabaseFile())); // autoload table
            // from disk if
            // possible
            initColumModel(); // reset table layout to defaults
        } else {
            createEmptyModel();
            table.setModel(model);
            initColumModel();
        }
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        addPopup(table, popupMenu);

        JMenuItem mntmAuftragHinzufgen = new JMenuItem("Auftrag hinzufügen");
        popupMenu.add(mntmAuftragHinzufgen);
        mntmAuftragHinzufgen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRow();
            }
        });

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_4 = new JMenuItem("Auftrag entfernen");
        popupMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_4);
        mntmNewMenuItem_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                removeSelectedRows();
            }
        });

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        splitPane.setRightComponent(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JButton buttonNewTask = new JButton("Neuer Auftrag");
        buttonNewTask.setBounds(12, 12, 174, 25);
        panel_1.add(buttonNewTask);
        buttonNewTask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addRow();
            }
        });

        JButton buttonDeleteTask = new JButton("Auftrag entfernen");
        buttonDeleteTask.setBounds(12, 49, 174, 25);
        panel_1.add(buttonDeleteTask);
        buttonDeleteTask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                removeSelectedRows();
            }
        });

        JButton buttonPrintTask = new JButton("Auftrag exportieren");
        buttonPrintTask.setBounds(198, 12, 174, 25);
        panel_1.add(buttonPrintTask);

        scrollPane_1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(745, 12, 600, 65);
        panel_1.add(scrollPane_1);
        infoList.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        // add info panel (list) containing runtime information
        infoList.setModel(infoListModel);
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(infoList);

        buttonPrintTask.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ExportTaskToPDF.exportTaskToPdf("Durchzuführende Baumaßnahmen", getSelectedTasksAsList());
            }
        });

        // scroll down to latest element
        table.scrollRectToVisible((table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true)));

        mainGui.setVisible(true);

        // add startup time to infoList
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        addInfo(((endTime - startTime) / 1000000) + " ms Startzeit");
    }

    public static void initColumModel() {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(81);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(81);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(81);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(134);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(123);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(95);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(95);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(226);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setResizable(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(102);
    }

    public static void saveModel(File filename) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;

        if (!config.getDatabaseFile().contains(".dbd")) {
            setDatabasePath();
            filename = new File(config.getDatabaseFile());
        }

        try {
            table.clearSelection(); // undo all selections to prevent user from
            // editing while saving
            if (table.isEditing()) { // prevent saving when user is editing a cell
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
            // detach model from table prior serializing
            out.writeObject(model);
            table.setModel(model); // re-attach table model

            initColumModel(); // set layout again

            out.writeObject(sequentialNumber);
        } catch (Exception errWrite) {
            errWrite.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Fehler beim speichern der Datenbank");
            addError("Fehler beim speichern der Datenbank");
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
                out.close();
                unsavedChanges = false;
            } catch (Exception errClose) {
                errClose.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Fehler beim Schließen der Dateiströme");
                addError("Fehler beim Schließen der Dateiströme");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void loadModel(File filename) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        if (!config.getDatabaseFile().contains(".dbd")) {
            setDatabasePath();
            filename = new File(config.getDatabaseFile());
        }

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            // TODO Lock database for application runtime to avoid conflicts
            // with other clients

            model = (DefaultTableModel) ois.readObject();
            sequentialNumber = (SequentialNumber) ois.readObject();

            table.setModel(model); // set the table model to the just loaded
            // one, this makes data appear
            initColumModel(); // make sure the layout fits

            ois.close();
            fis.close();

            addInfo(model.getRowCount() + " Datensätze erfolgreich geladen");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException errNotFound) {
            addError("Datenbank konnte nicht gefunden werden, öffne leere Datenbank");
            errNotFound.printStackTrace();
            createEmptyModel();
            table.setModel(model);
        } catch (IOException errIO) {
            System.out.println("Datei konnte nicht gelesen werden (IO Exception)");
            errIO.printStackTrace();
            if (filechooserOpen == true) {
                addError("Fehler beim Lesen der Datenbank! (IO Exception)");
            } else {
                addError("Fehler beim Lesen der Datenbank! (IO Exception) Öffne jetzt mit leerer Datenbank!");
                createEmptyModel();
                table.setModel(model);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException errClassNotFound) {
            System.out.println("Klasse zum Deserialisieren nicht gefunden");
            errClassNotFound.printStackTrace();
            addError("Fehler beim Lesen der Datenbank! (Datenbank veraltet). Erstelle jetzt neue Datenbank!");
            createEmptyModel();
            table.setModel(model);
        }
    }

    public static void setDatabasePath() {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int fcRetrunValue = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

        if ((fcRetrunValue != JFileChooser.ABORT && fcRetrunValue != JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
                && fc.getSelectedFile().toString().contains(".dbd")) {
            do {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainGui, "Bitte wählen Sie das richtige Dateiformat (.dbd)", "",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                int fcReturnValueInLoop = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

                if (fcReturnValueInLoop == JFileChooser.ABORT || fcReturnValueInLoop == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    break; // prevent infinite file chooser
                } else if (fc.getSelectedFile().toString().contains(".dbd")) {
                    config.setDatabaseFile(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());
                    break;
                }
            } while (!fc.getSelectedFile().toString().contains(".dbd"));
        } else {
            if (fc.getSelectedFile().toString() != "" && fc.getSelectedFile().toString().contains(".dbd")) {
                config.setDatabaseFile(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addRow() {
        // get current date
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        // sequential number represents some kind of primary key in the database
        sequentialNumber.increase();
        model.addRow(new Object[] { sequentialNumber.getNumber(), "FB", null, null, timeStamp, null, null, null, null,
                null, null, null });
        // scroll to last row
        table.scrollRectToVisible((table.getCellRect(table.getRowCount() - 1, 0, true)));
        unsavedChanges = true; // ask upon close to save changes
    }

    public static void removeSelectedRows() {
        // create int array that contains the row numbers of the user selection
        int selectedRows[] = table.getSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
            // [i] - i to take into account that the lines shift while removing
            model.removeRow(selectedRows[i] - i);
            unsavedChanges = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize an empty table with default settings
     */

    private static void createEmptyModel() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {},
                new String[] { "Lfd. Nr.", "FB Nr.", "Auftr. / Meld. Nr.", "Betra Nr.", "Datum", "Bahnhof", "Str. Km.",
                        "Sprz.", "Arb. Zeit", "Mitarbeiter", "Auftrag / Objekt(e)", "Abgeschlossen" }) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 3701695679244364045L;

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[] { Integer.class, String.class, Long.class, Long.class, String.class,
                    String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class };

            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        };

        sequentialNumber.reset();
    }

    public static ArrayList<Object[]> getSelectedTasksAsList() {
        ArrayList<Object[]> tasks = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        if (table.getSelectedRowCount() > 0) { // check if there are selected
            // rows
            int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows(); // get a list of
            // selected rows
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) { // print all
                // selected tasks
                Object[] taskAsArray = new Object[table.getColumnCount() - 1];
                for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount() - 1; j++) {
                    // add all columns from currently processed row to Object
                    // array
                    if ((table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),
                            // avoid null pointer exception if column is empty
                            table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j))) != null) {

                        taskAsArray[j] = (table.getValueAt(table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRows[i]),
                                table.convertColumnIndexToModel(j)));
                    } else
                        taskAsArray[j] = new String("");
                }
                tasks.add(taskAsArray);
            }
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    public void restart() {
        // TODO implement function to restart app
    }

    public void updateApp() {
        // TODO implement function to self-update the application
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void compareDates(String date1, String date2) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        LocalDate localDate1 = formatter.parseLocalDate(date1);
        LocalDate localDate2 = formatter.parseLocalDate(date2);

        if (localDate1.isAfter(localDate2)) {
            System.out.println("date1 comes after date2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("date1 comes before date2");
        }
    }

    private static void addPopup(Component component, final JPopupMenu popup) {
        component.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    showMenu(e);
                }
            }

            private void showMenu(MouseEvent e) {
                popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void addInfo(String message) {
        infoList.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        infoListModel.addElement("[INFO]: " + message);
        // make sure last index is visible else scroll accordingly
        infoList.ensureIndexIsVisible(infoList.getModel().getSize() - 1);
    }

    public static void addWarning(String message) {
        infoList.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        infoListModel.addElement("[WARN]: " + message);
        infoList.ensureIndexIsVisible(infoList.getModel().getSize() - 1);
    }

    public static void addError(String message) {
        infoList.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        infoListModel.addElement("[ERROR]: " + message);
        infoList.ensureIndexIsVisible(infoList.getModel().getSize() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the relevant code.

Comment: Ugh this is a very long class...

Comment: There you go. Let me know if you need help understanding the code.

Comment: Well, have you filed a bug against Eclipse / Window Builder?

Comment: Currently at work. I will do this this afternoon. But I think my error log is not really sufficient enough. I need to get more output first. I will also try again on windows, because Windowbuilder seems to be very unstable on Linux still.

Comment: It's perfectly parsing with Eclipse Mars on Windows. Love the Windowbuilder on Linux -.-